# ScriptSharp 0.7.4 - Where is ScriptFx (or equivalent functionality)

Tags: script#

I've been asked to port a large body of existing Script# code to the latest version (from some version in 2009, roughly 0.5-ish, I believe), and most of it is fairly rote - Use System.Xml vs. System.XML, System.Html vs. System.DHTML, Element vs. DOMElement (only provided this many examples in case it helps identify the version I'm converting from).

However, 0.7.4 seems to be missing ScriptFx entirely, and mscorlib's System.ComponentModel doesn't contain INotifyPropertyChanged or PropertyChangedEventHandler/Args, which are used by the codebase I'm converting.

Where did they go?  If they're gone, what should I use in their stead?  I've looked through the samples and I don't see anything directly relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptFX functionality has been deprecated and then removed for some time now.

A new one in its place is just coming into existence... it will cover some of the similar functionality (eg. behaviors, bindings), as well as more needed to create a modern HTML application.

See https://github.com/nikhilk/sharpen.

Its not quite ready for primetime, but hopefully you'll start to get a sense, and be able to follow along.

Comment: Is it ready for prime time yet? I have a similar pile of rotten code wholly dependent on ScriptFX